# Angular: ng-view not displaying anything

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular so I can get into web app development. I'm doing a test project but can't get ng-view to work. My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST PROJECT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_project.css">
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='TestProject'>

    <center>
    <div class="interface" ng-controller="SelectionController">
        <div style="height: 10%">
        <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com"><img style="margin:5px; float:left; height: 10vh" src="pictures/logo.gif"></a>
        <center><h1>{{ title }}</h1></center>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 85%" ng-view></div>

        <div style="height:5%">
        <p>Having trouble? <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/contact.shtml">Request Support</a>
        <p style="bottom: 50px; position:fixed; size:8px">Footer Text
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>


    <script src="angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('TestProject',['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller:     'SelectionController',
            templateUrl:    '/views/home.html'
    })
        .when('/home/', {
            controller:     'SelectionController',
            templateUrl:    '/views/home.html'
    })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home/'
    });
});
```

As well as controllers.js, which currently only has:

```
app.controller('SelectionController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Title!';

}]);
```

And then I have a home.html,

```
<div>
<h2>Welcome to this page! Please select an option below.</h2>
            <table>
                <td><div><img class="Symbol" src="../pictures/pica.jpg"></div></td>
                <td><div><img class="Symbol" src="../pictures/picb.jpg"></div></td>
                <td><div><img class="Symbol" src="../pictures/picc.jpg"></div></td>
            </table>
</div>
```

which SHOULD be loaded into ng-view. My aim is to make a single page where the center div of the window changes so I can load different screens to do whatever the app does without reloading the other stuff. The current directory structure is like this:

```
--angular
------app
------controllers
--lib
------angular.min
------angular-animate.min
------angular-route.min
------Chart.js
------jquery-1.11.3
--pictures
------pica
------picb
------picc
--views
------home.html
index.html
test.css
```

What I have now makes {{ title }} change the way it's supposed to, but there's nothing in the middle of the page. When I inspect the page, I see that the `ng-view` directive is commented.

```
<-- ngView: undefined -->
```

Is where my content from home.html is supposed to be. Why is ngView being commented out here?

Comment: Are you sure the path to the view is correct (it may be relative to the website root, not the "`app.js`" root)?  Although it may be trivial, please post the view source as well.

Comment: Ive added the view source and an outline of where stuff is in the directory

Comment: Change your route to be: `templateUrl : '/views/home.html'` - notice the casing on `Url`.  Also, update the path to be "root based"

Comment: I did the first two things and updated the OP, but I dont know what you mean by update the path to be root based

Comment: Did it make a difference?  Is there anything logged to the console that details an error?

Comment: OH, yeah there is. I didn't notice it before. The ng-view is still commented out, but the errors showing are 

1. "Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Fviews%2Fhome.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined

and 2. Error: Access to restricted URI denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html file that you show should be:

This file should be the index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST PROJECT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_project.css">
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='TestProject'>

  <div ng-view></div>

<script src="angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="angular/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then create a new html file, should be as you have in the routeProvider, and should be inside inside view folder, as it view/home.html

And content must be:

```
<div class="interface" ng-controller="SelectionController">
    <div style="height: 10%">
    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com"><img style="margin:5px; float:left; height: 10vh" src="pictures/logo.gif"></a>
    <center><h1>{{ title }}</h1></center>
    </div>
    <div style="height:5%">
    <p>Having trouble? <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/contact.shtml">Request Support</a>
    <p style="bottom: 50px; position:fixed; size:8px">Footer Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Thats the way angular works.

Regards.

Comment: So are you saying that I can't have all that content in the second block in my index.html? Because I wanted that stuff to be static, and just have a div in between teh 10% block and the 5% block where I change stuff.

Comment: No - the way he has it is fine.  In fact, I am working on an angular app that does just the same.

Comment: yes could be, but the problem is that your are using routeProvider you was not correctly configuring the view.  Take a sample here, there details what i want to explain, and of course, you can use div percent, and have some views in the same static file, but first, check this guide: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: I noticed that he has `templateURL` instead of `templateUrl`, which could be the issue.

Comment: @MaxPinto Ah - also missed that he has the `{{title}}` in the index page.

Comment: yes, that right, for that reason i put to the template view, that is filled with the routeProvider... i recommend to read the guide i sent before @Zephyr. Regards

Comment: Well I'd like the top and bottom to stay static, and only have whatever is in the middle to change. So what if I had a separate controller for the whole page that can change the {{title}}, but in the routing part I use a different controller that only applies to the view?

Answer (score 1):

I had this EXACT issue. what resolved it for me was, as Brendan Green mentioned,
changing my route to be `: templateUrl`  instead of `: templateURL` ...casing made a huge difference!!!!